# UITableView's indexPathsForSelectedRows: doesn't get updated when inserting new rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that get's new rows on top periodically and supports multiple selection.

The problem is that `indexPathsForSelectedRows:` doesn't get properly updated in the next row insertion.

I would suppose it doesn't get updated at all and try to come up with a better way to track selected cells, but it does get updated in subsequent row insertions.

I added some log statements to test it:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection: %@", @(_messages.count));
    return _messages.count;
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"willSelectRowAtIndexPath: %@ indexPathsForSelectedRows: %@", indexPath, tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows);
    return indexPath;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath: %@ indexPathsForSelectedRows: %@", indexPath, tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows);
}
```

---

Additionally I log `indexPathsForSelectedRows` when returning the height of a cell that should be selected:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Selected cell?
    if ([tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        NSLogInfo(@"indexPathsForSelectedRows: %@", tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows);
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

Relevant code that adds/removes rows:

```
- (void)updateTableViewRowsRemoving:(NSInteger)itemsToRemoveCount
                          inserting:(NSInteger)itemsToInsertCount
{
    // Code to calculate removePaths and insertPaths
    // ...

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    if (itemsToRemoveCount > 0)
    {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:removePaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        NSLogVerbose(@"deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: %@", removePaths);
    }
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertPaths
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    NSLogVerbose(@"insertRowsAtIndexPaths: %@", insertPaths);
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Another test where I let first appear two rows, then select the last row (`1`). A new row is added on top and the selected row is still `1` and only after it starts getting updated.

```
2014-04-11 14:28:55.653 ConsoleDemo[77409:60b] numberOfRowsInSection: 0
2014-04-11 14:29:01.939 ConsoleDemo[77409:60b] numberOfRowsInSection: 1
2014-04-11 14:29:09.241 ConsoleDemo[77409:60b] insertRowsAtIndexPaths: (
    "<NSIndexPath: 0x8d7e610> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}"
)
2014-04-11 14:29:09.242 ConsoleDemo[77409:60b] numberOfRowsInSection: 2
2014-04-11 14:29:10.584 ConsoleDemo[77409:60b] willSelectRowAtIndexPath: <NSIndexPath: 0x8f82820> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1} indexPathsForSelectedRows: (null)
2014-04-11 14:29:10.584 ConsoleDemo[77409:60b] didSelectRowAtIndexPath: <NSIndexPath: 0x8f82820> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1} indexPathsForSelectedRows: (
    "<NSIndexPath: 0x8f81440> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}"
)
2014-04-11 14:29:14.741 ConsoleDemo[77409:60b] insertRowsAtIndexPaths: (
    "<NSIndexPath: 0x8c774e0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}"
)
2014-04-11 14:29:14.742 ConsoleDemo[77409:60b] numberOfRowsInSection: 3
2014-04-11 14:29:14.742 ConsoleDemo[77409:60b] indexPathsForSelectedRows: (
    "<NSIndexPath: 0x8f81440> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}"
)
2014-04-11 14:29:20.443 ConsoleDemo[77409:60b] insertRowsAtIndexPaths: (
    "<NSIndexPath: 0x8e7fe60> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}"
)
2014-04-11 14:29:20.444 ConsoleDemo[77409:60b] numberOfRowsInSection: 4
2014-04-11 14:29:20.444 ConsoleDemo[77409:60b] indexPathsForSelectedRows: (
    "<NSIndexPath: 0x8ccd300> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}"
)
```

Comment: Where are you logging the `indexPathsForSelectedRows` besides the two methods you posted in your question?

Comment: It would probably help to show your code for adding the additional rows. The log output would seem to indicate the 2nd row being added is really being added after the 1st row and then the 3rd and 4th are added before the 1st row.

Comment: Cleaned up the question and added log messages when inserting rows. New rows are always inserted at `path = 0 - 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finished [manually keeping track](https://github.com/PTEz/LumberjackConsole/blob/master/Source/PTEConsoleLogger.m#L375) of selected objects in the `dataSource`.